# Draggable Fullscreen slides with TweenLite, CSSPlugin and ScrollToPlugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, draggable, gsap

i'm new with the GreenSocks Tween library, and i'm wondering if there was a way to extends an available "full-page-mousewheel-scrollable" gallery with the `drag` event, to go to next/prev slide.

In [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/yucoqaxusu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) i've copied all the code and libs of the gallery from [this post article](http://bassta.bg/2014/04/fullscreen-slides-with-tweenlite-cssplugin-and-scrolltoplugin/#comment-1380).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/)?

[Here is a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/maxuni/4/edit?js,output)

**Added this code**

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('hammer');
var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement,{
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe,{ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL }]
    ]
});
hammertime.on('swipeup', goToNextSlide);
hammertime.on('swipedown', goToPrevSlide);
```

Comment: hi @whoacowboy, thanks for the demo. i know and used hammer.js, and i think is very good for the touch event, and in your demo it working very well. but, i'm looking for the drag event, not the swipe: both event are in most part pretty similar, but i would like to touch and drag, not touch and wait to the event swipe end and call the function. :-)

Comment: hi @GiacomoPaita, by drag do you mean after mousedown and mousemove up/down the slide is dragged with it? When you let go it slides to the nearest slide?

Comment: Yes, kind of the OWL Carousel can achieve out of the box, see the example here: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/. About the TweenLite ScrollTo Carousel, i wondering if it was possible to use a built in drag function / method given in the library it self. Sorry for my bad english... :-)